# Lucene IndexWriter.AddDocument slow after changing architecture to x64

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, lucene, lucene.net

I have a asp.net core web app that uses Lucene.net 3.0.3 and is currently using x86 architecture:

```
<TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
<RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

When writing documents to our index, the process is smooth - calling `IndexWriter.AddDocument` takes less than a second and there are **no** records that stall.

We tried moving to `win7-x64`, but we noticed that our lucene reindexing takes much longer. For the most part, calling IndexWriter.AddDocument takes the same amount of time on `x86` and `x64`. However, on `x64`, at intervals of about a couple of thousand of records - there will be a document that takes 15 seconds on `IndexWriter.AddDocument`!

Any ideas as to why this is happening and/or how to debug and fix it?

This is what the code looks like:

```
private void AddItemToIndex(TInput indexItem, IndexWriter writer)
{
    var searchQuery = new TermQuery(new Term("Id", NumericUtils.IntToPrefixCoded(indexItem.Id)));
    writer.DeleteDocuments(searchQuery);

    var document = GetDocumentsFromIndexItem(indexItem);

    //this is the line that will sometimes take 15 seconds
    writer.AddDocument(document); 
}

private Document GetDocumentsFromIndexItem(LuceneIndexItemDto item)
{
    var indexDocument = new Document();
    indexDocument.Add(new NumericField(nameof(item.Id), Field.Store.YES, true).SetIntValue(item.Id));

    indexDocument.Add(new Field($"{nameof(item.Id)}String", item.Id.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    indexDocument.Add(new Field(nameof(item.Title), item.Title ?? "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    indexDocument.Add(new Field(nameof(item.Description), item.Description ?? "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

    foreach (var note in item.Notes)
    {
        indexDocument.Add(new Field(nameof(item.Notes), note ?? "", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
    }

    return indexDocument;
}
```

**UPDATE 1:** 
I started debugging through Lucene.net and I found that the stall happens when Lucene calls Flush. So, its the flushing that is taking a long period of time.

Answer (score 1):

Since you code looks ok, this is advice how to try and debug this.

First of all, you have to log all information from Lucene somewhere, so you will know what is going on. Write your own [Lucene.Net.Util.InfoStream](https://lucenenetdocs.azurewebsites.net/api/Lucene.Net/Lucene.Net.Util.InfoStream.html), and write all information to the database. Here is a sample, how to write it using log4net:

```
public class Log4NetInfoStream : InfoStream
{
    private readonly ILog _log;

    public Log4NetInfoStream()
    {
        _log = LogManager.GetLogger(GetType());
    }

    public override bool IsEnabled(string component)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override void Message(string component, string message)
    {
        _log.DebugFormat("{0} :: {1}", component, message);
    }
}
```

Then when your program start, set it up:

```
Lucene.Net.Util.InfoStream.Default = new Log4NetInfoStream();
```

After that you will be able to inspect, what is going on in your application.

If that won't help, install [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), and check where exactly is this 15 seconds delay. I have a feeling this is not Lucene related, but something is wrong with your machine. Maybe it cannot access something, some network drive or proxy. This tool will show you that.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I will try. Not sure if you saw my update - The slowness happens when lucene calls flush. A flush is only occasionally triggered when I call `writer.AddDocument(document);` I guess Lucene forces a flush after a certain memory size limit has been reached. Does that give you any new ideas?

Comment: update: I played around with some of the settings and setting the RAMBufferSizeMB to 4 (`writer.SetRAMBufferSizeMB(4);`) made the process fast again (down from 6 minutes to 1 minute 42 seconds)

Comment: I was about to suggest to check `writer.RamSizeInBytes()` and maybe add manual `writer.Flush(true, true)` or `writer.Commit()`.